# Unable to click File->open->project/Solution or Help->Technical support on visual studio using pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

Unable to click File->open->project/Solution or Help->Technical support on Visual Studio using pywinauto.

I am trying to automate application similar to Visual Studio:

```
 from pywinauto.application import Application
import time
app = Application(backend="uia").Start(cmd_line=u'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\\devenv.exe"')

vshwndwrapper = app["Start Page - Microsoft Visual Studio"]
vshwndwrapper.wait('ready')
app.window(title_re='Start*').MenuBar.MenuBarClick('#9->#0', app)
```

Comment: Use `Application(backend="uia")` for Visual Studio.

Comment: you mean to say  `Application(backend="uia").Start(cmd_line=u'"\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe"')` ?

Comment: Sure. Just try `.dump_tree()` for main window using both backends. You will see the difference. :)

Comment: Aplication itself is not starting after changing to Application(backend="uia").Start  File "C:\python_27_amd64\files\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1207, in window
    raise AppNotConnected("Please use start or connect before trying "
pywinauto.application.AppNotConnected: Please use start or connect before trying anything else

Comment: above error is comming

Comment: Can you edit the question and show the whole code? Probably you missed something in calling method `.start(...)`. But the error happens on next line.

Comment: I edit my code and pasted my version of code

Comment: I posted the code how it looks on my PC. Which exact menu item or toolbar button do you need to click?

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine to me:

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application(backend="uia").start(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"')
app['Microsoft Visual Studio'].dump_tree()
```

It prints a lot of elements available for actions.
If you omit `backend="uia"` it prints only these very few elements ("Start" page is disabled in my instance of Visual Studio 2015):

```
Control Identifiers:

HwndWrapper[DefaultDomain;;9f36883a-fdb6-4b48-ae9e-5ccdabe22dd2] - 'Microsoft Visual Studio'    (L-8, T-8, R1688, B1018)
[u'Microsoft Visual StudioHwndWrapper[DefaultDomain;;9f36883a-fdb6-4b48-ae9e-5ccdabe22dd2]', u'HwndWrapper[DefaultDomain;;9f36883a-fdb6-4b48-ae9e-5ccdabe22dd2]', u'Microsoft Visual Studio']
child_window(title="Microsoft Visual Studio", class_name="HwndWrapper[DefaultDomain;;9f36883a-fdb6-4b48-ae9e-5ccdabe22dd2]")
   | 
   | GenericPane - 'Toolbox - Initializing'    (L1470, T130, R1673, B960)
   | [u'GenericPane', u'ToolboxGenericPane', u'Toolbox']
   | child_window(title="Toolbox - Initializing", class_name="GenericPane")
   |    | 
   |    | TBToolboxPane - ''    (L1470, T130, R1673, B960)
   |    | [u'Microsoft Visual StudioTBToolboxPane', u'TBToolboxPane']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TBToolboxPane")
   | 
   | TBToolboxPane - ''    (L1470, T130, R1673, B960)
   | [u'Microsoft Visual StudioTBToolboxPane', u'TBToolboxPane']
   | child_window(class_name="TBToolboxPane")
```

Default backend is `"win32"` which means old Win32 API technology, while `"uia"` means UI Automation API which was introduced in Windows Vista (though can be installed on WinXP as well).

I would strongly recommend reading the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) which explains the core concept of the library. And please surf another documents around it. You may find a lot of useful information.